# How to get current time in milliseconds in Haxe?

Tags: datetime, time, haxe, hxcpp

I need a function that returns the local time in milliseconds on the CPP target.

I tried Haxe's `Date` class, but `Date.now()` gives me the time in seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Sys.time() * 1000.0` - http://api.haxe.org/Sys.html#time

> Gives the most precise timestamp value (in seconds)

To be clear, I tried this and got millisecond resolution on the cpp target. `Sys` is available on cpp, cs, java, macro, neko, php and python.

Comment: Though I must say I find it kinda disturbing that this just has float precision. At least from C++, one is used to much better precision.

Comment: I suppose it's easier to implement a single method across platforms if you pass a float back. Here's how it's implemented for cpp: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/blob/735bf91da2059dd2c510596f90f13dbf7345bf56/project/libs/std/Sys.cpp#L507

Comment: they should really change the documentation and return milliseconds - else if useless unless you see this answer.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP Remember that haxe floats are 64-bit, so you actually get 56 bits of integer precision.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [`Date.now().getTime()`](http://api.haxe.org/Date.html#getTime), however:

> Returns the timestamp of the date. **It might only have a per-second precision depending on the platforms**.

Comment: Doesn't work for cpp target. Maybe I should edit my question.

Comment: Yes, this only gives me per-second precision on the cpp target i.e: 1453822269000, 1453822270000...

Answer (score 0):

A fast way of getting a timestamp would be to use the `haxe.Timer.stamp()` method.

**Example**:

```
import haxe.Timer;

var timestamp:Float = Timer.stamp(); // return a timestamp in seconds with fractions
```

Note that the value itself might differ depending on platforms, only differences between two values make sense.